# i need to return a value from a dataframe cell as a variable not a series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8, pandas-loc

i have the following issue:

when i use `.loc` funtion it returns a `series` not a single `value` with no `index`.
As i need to do some math operation with the selected cells. the function that i am using is:

```
import pandas as pd
 

data = [[82,1], [30, 2], [3.7, 3]]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Ah-Step', 'State'])
df['Ah-Step'].loc[df['State']==2]+ df['Ah-Step'].loc[df['State']==3]
```

Comment: can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the dataframe?

Comment: i have done it.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: my desired output would be just 30+3.7=33.7.. but this is a simplification of what i want since i have to  do alot of different math operations. so would benefit me alot if i can return a signle variable not series when i locat any cell in a data frame.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076528/7109869) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.values[0]` will do what OP wants.

Assuming one wants to obtain the value 30, the following will do the work

```
df.loc[df['State'] == 2, 'Ah-Step'].values[0]

print(df)

[Out]: 30.0
```

So, in OP's specific case, the operation 30+3.7 could be done as follows

```
df.loc[df['State'] == 2, 'Ah-Step'].values[0] + df['Ah-Step'].loc[df['State']==3].values[0]

[Out]: 33.7
```